# How to make sed script replace in file?

Tags: shell, sed

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/","/|/g;                  # global change of "," to bar
# do some more stuff
#s/|/","/g;                  # global change of bar back to ","
#---end of script---
```

The above script removes the 2nd field from a CSV, and clears out quotes and such. I didn't include most of the script because it's not pertinent to the question.

The script is saved in the file `fix.sh`.

I can run it on a file like this:

```
$ ./fix.sh <myfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

And it works great.

But I want it to replace in file. This doesn't work:

```
$ ./fix.sh <myfile.txt >myfile.txt
```

It results in an empty `myfile.txt`.

This doesn't work either:

```
$ ./fix.sh myfile.txt
```

I tried finding some documentation on `sed` bash scripts but didn't find anything to help me.

I'm sure the answer is simple, I just can't find it. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that this is running on a CentOS 6 machine.

Full script is below. Its overall result is to remove field#2 and strip quotes.

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
# adapted from http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_005.html
s/","/|/g;                  # global change of "," to bar
s/^"//;
s/"$//;
s/^\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|/\1|/;   # delete 2nd field contents
s/||/|/;                        # change || to |
s/ //g;                         # remove spaces
s/|/,/g;
#s/|/","/g;                  # global change of bar back to ","
#---end of script---
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `sed` supports `-i` option then you can run your script like this:

```
./fix.sh -i myfile.txt
```

`-i` option of `sed` does the in-file substitutions.

If your version of `sed` does not support the `-i` option then you can do the following which is pretty much the same thing that `-i` does behind the scene:

```
./fix.sh myfile.txt > temp && mv temp myfile.txt
```

#### Why redirecting to the same file doesn't work?

The reason is that the redirection opens the file for writing and ends up clearing any existing contents. `sed` then tries to read this empty file, and does nothing. The file is then closed and there by you get an empty file.

Comment: I use `-i` on the command line and it works. But using it with my script gave me an empty file. Your second solution also gave me an empty file. Does this have anything to do with my script header?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: This answer seems to be right +1, however you might be getting empty file because of some other commands in your script. I suggest you post your full script in your question so that we can investigate.

Comment: Note that `sed` on Mac OS X accepts `-i` but requires an extension for a backup copy of the file, unlike GNU `sed`.  If you're on Mac OS X, that might be a factor in your problem.  Did you remove the I/O redirection when you ran the command?  That could be another problem.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Anubhava, both are valid and good points. @ButtleButkus you will need to update the question with your script to do proper debugging. You can try adding one sed command at a time in your script and run it against your file. The command which will result in empty file will be the command that would need tweaking.

Comment: @ButtleButkus You are using `-n` in the first line which suppreses the printing action. Put `p;` at the end of your script after `s/|/,/g;` line (just before the comments). This will enable print action.